# Infinite scrolling in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, infinite-scroll

I'm working on an application where I want to create an infinite scrolling. I dont want to use plug-ins to achieve infinite scroll. Here's my .js.erb file:

```
  $("#container1").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shirts/first')%>");

<% if @first.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate(@first) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
<% sleep 1 %>
```

And here is the coffeescript code:

```
jQuery ->
if $('.pagination').length
  $(window).scroll ->
  url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
  $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
  $.getScript(url)
  $(window).scroll()
```

Am i doing it properly because the infinite scrolling isn't working. Help me out with this, I'm new to rails!

Comment: Can you hit the ajax url on it's own and get results?  Look a the log to see that it's a successful request.  If so - check the response in developer tools (it will be in javascript) and try it in console to see what it does to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I can't debug it unless I'm on your computer, but try and follow these steps:

1. Console.log  the event when you get to that window position via your scrollTop function to make sure it is getting triggered.
2. Check your json or whatever response in the chrome debugger, going to network and watching for the ajax request, making sure that the url request and request type is correct. (This error can be anywhere, from your database, to your controller and view.)
3. Console.log the results of the request to make sure that the data is what you require.
4. Check the html of that which is returned or that you want to output in the console.
5. Try to append anything to the specified div.
6. Try to append something with 'escape javascript'
7. Don't skip steps.

Cheers :)